# Redirect a Post Request in Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, redirect

i'm a beginner in node.js and trying to redirect a post request. here is the code snippet

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const passport = require('passport');
const router = require('express').Router();
const auth = require('../auth');
const Users = mongoose.model('Users');

router.post('/createuser', auth.required, (req, res, next) => {
    const { payload: { id } } = req;
    //var id = req.get("authorization");
  console.log("in create User route");

    return Users.findById(id)
      .then((user) => {
        if(!user) {
          return res.sendStatus(400);
        }

        //res.send(req.body);

        res.redirect(307,'http://localhost:8181/user');
      });
  });
```

I hit the URL from Advance Rest Client and get this statement

```
"Temporary Redirect. Redirecting to http://localhost:8181/user"
```

but there is no redirection. i also tried

```
res.redirect(302,'http://localhost:8181/user');
```

and

```
res.redirect('http://localhost:8181/user');
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you share the code of route '/user' ?

Comment: And why are you returning the promise "return Users.findById(id).then()...." ?

Comment: the route /user is an API in java and it does nothing but send a string back, here is the code 

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/user")
    public String createUser(@RequestBody Userdb user)
    {
     
     System.out.println("******** in the create user route : "+user.getUsername());
       //Integer id =  userService.createUser(user);
        
       // return "user created with  "+id+" ID " ;
     
    
 return "user created";
    }


and return Users.findById(id) is to authenticate user, we can ignore this part for now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not tried this using express. But below code works in node.

```
res.writeHead(302,{'Location':'url/test'});
res.end();
```

Comment: Hi, can u tell me what do i put in 'Location'

Answer (score 0):

Just do `res.redirect('/myroutes');` You don't need to declare your host as well.